# Java. Странное поведение Calendar

Tags: java, дата

Я использую такой синтаксис:

```
 System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

И все работает верно выводит `21` и сегодня 21е число.

Но когда я посылаю:

```
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Мне печатает `11` хотя сейчас 12-ый месяц.

Почему это происходит, как исправить? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Месяцы считаются с нуля

Comment: Вот это неожиданно... Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать GreagorianCalendar, наследника от Calendar